# Not getting any output from submit button on select box using jquery,Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, select

Hello i have select box from which i want to select news from last 4,6 weeks and show news accordingly based on submit button. I have used following code to create jquery,ajax and trying to pass value to php. But i dont know when i select from select box and click on submit button nothing will show.I think i am doing something serious wrong not able to communicate properly with php and jquery,ajax.Here is Jsfiddle:[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z5B6n/4/).Thanks
Here is my code:

dashboard.php

```
if($param['aktion'] == 'get-widget-news-edit')
{
    if(isset($_POST['saveId']))
   {

      if(($_POST['news'])==4){

      echo "You have selected news for last 4 weeks";

}

 if(($_POST['news'])==6){

     echo "You have selected news for last 6 weeks";
}
}

    $html = '<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
            <tr>
                <td>
                <div>'.CreateRegister($page['register-news']).'</div>
                '.CreateMessage().'
                <div class="cont-liste-verlauf register">
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div id="tab1" class="tab" style="display:block">
                            <table id="news">

                            <form name="UserInformationForm" method="POST" >

                        <select name="news">
                                <option value="4" '. (($_POST['news']=="4")  ?  "selected=selected" : "" ) .'>Show news from last 4 weeks</option>
                                <option value="6" '. (($_POST['news']=="6") ?  "selected=selected" : "") .'>Show news from last 6 weeks</option>

                        </select>
                        <br/><br/>
                    <input type="Submit" name="saveId" id="saveId">

                            </form> 
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>';

    $return = array(
    'status' => 1,
    'html'  => $html
);

echo json_encode($return);
die();
```

}

dashboard.js

```
function getNewsWidgetEdit()
    {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/dashboard.php",
        dataType : 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: {'aktion' : 'get-widget-news-edit'},
        success: function(data){
            $('#news').html(data.html);

        }
      });
  }


            $('#news .butt-rahmen').live('click', function(){
            if($(this).attr('id') == 'saveId')
                getNewsWidgetEdit();


    });
```

Comment: You do not gives `$_POST['saveId']` or `$_POST['news']`. Check to [serialize your form](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: can you please tell me how to use it here in my code because i am new to use serialize form option...

Comment: Simply `data: { $( "form" ).serialize() }` and then you can retrieve all data of your form in your PHP file with POST. Because I guess for the moment you retrieve empty data.

Comment: Hi thanks i have done that also but still its not showing anything. i am very much near to the result but doing small mistake . I have updated ur answer in fiddle can you please check: http://jsfiddle.net/z5B6n/6/

Comment: i guess we dont even have to click on button to get the result now as per your answer if it works

Comment: I don't see any changes. Anyway have you put the `header('Content-Type: application/json')` as @user574632 tells you.

Comment: Hi if you see i have added showvalue() function in fiddle and i have put ('Content-Type: application/json') also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending json from your php, so change datatype to html and append the raw data:

```
    dataType : 'html',
    cache: false,
    data: {'aktion' : 'get-widget-news-edit'},
    success: function(data){
        $('#news').html(data);

    }
```

OR change your php to send json:

```
if(($_POST['news'])==4){
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('html'=>'You have selected news for last 4 weeks'));
    exit();
```

Comment: Hi please check the updated question, i have made changes for json format but still its not giving me output.Actually its not the error of data type in my code, the actual error i think i am not able to pass id..because i did other code in json data type and they were running fine..

Comment: @user3702602 i dont see any changes in your update, did you try either of my solutions

Comment: hi what changes you have made same i updated in my question,please check at the bottom in dashboard.php, i m returning array and echoing in js format..

Comment: @user3702602 why are you returning the form html? Surely you want to just return the message, as per my answer?

Comment: Hi but it tried in your answer way too but its not returning anything and give me an error saying data is null from ajax...